# How to reuse business logic on both front-end and back-end?

Tags: ajax, design-patterns, frontend, backend, properties-file

I have a slightly complicated control flow with a bunch of if statements laying out steps for when certain fields in a form need to be highlighted (with different colors), the fields also auto-populate based on certain parameters; on top of that different fields need to show up upon different inputs.

I also have a need to use this same logic on the backend for generating reports and such.

I tried to extract the logic into a properties file, and then have the backend and frontend read that file and implement the logic as necessary.

However after a point this got too unwieldy, and I ended up writing code inside my properies file:

```
rules = [{field: 'xyz', 
          conditions: [{value: 50, 
                        highlight_fields: {color: 'red', fields: [...]}},
                        show_fields: ....
                        custom_rule: ....
                       {value_between: [90,100], 
                        highlight_fields...}]}
  ...
```

You can image this getting quite large with a each type of value_XYZ requirement. I also then need to add that rule to the properties file reader (on both sides)--which defeats the purpose of encapsulating the logic into a separate properties file.

Is there any sane method where I can achieve clean encapsulation of business logic that can be used across different technologies?

I could handle everything on the backend side, having the front-end call ajax calls to the backend system to get the proper highlighting rules, but that might not be fast enough over the wire.

Comment: You could create a little library in javascript and generate all special logic (js) on the server. Generating the logic will eliminate the need to copy it all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you do not want to use this checks on both sides, because this violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and increase application complexity.

But using approach with properties file is an overhead too. Somebody, who will try to understand this logic, will be frustrated.

Storing this logic on the back end side isn't looks like a bad solution. With modern networks, such a common task as server side validation via *AJAX*, shouldn't be a problem. So it's worth to make a simple proof of concept, to be sure that this approach will satisfy you.

If latency is so critical for you, you can take a look to *[web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)* technology. Lower latency is one of it's advantages vs *AJAX*.